# Play one video each month using vb.net in HTML

Tags: vb.net

I have a web application using vb.net. The application plays a video looping all the time. I need to change the video each month manually. How can I do to change the video automatically with the change of the month?

I have this code in HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Fullscreen Video</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="fullscreen-bg">
        <video id="video1" muted autoplay class="fullscreen-bg__video">
            <source src="http://euspsql01/prevencion/video/6.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
            </video>
    </div>

    <div class="content">


    </div>

</body>
</html>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    document.getElementById('video1').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);


    function myHandler(e) {
        window.location.href = "http://euspsql01/Prevencion";
    }

</script>
```

And this other code in an aspx.vb(only a test, not working):

```
Public Class video
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Public mes As String = Today.Month 'guarda el numero de mes actual en la variable mes
    Public rutavideo As String = "Http://euspsql01/prevencion/video/" And mes And ".mp4"

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: `Public mes As String = Today.Month` You have a problem right here. Today.Month returns an Integer, not a String. Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: This is a problem too. `Public rutavideo As String = "Http://euspsql01/prevencion/video/" And mes And ".mp4"` The concatenation character in vb.net is the ampersand (&) Try `"Http://euspsql01/prevencion/video/" & mes & ".mp4"` once you fix the first problem.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need one server control in your HTML. I would use Literal:

```
<video id="video1" muted autoplay class="fullscreen-bg__video">
    <asp:Literal ID="litSource" runat="server" />
</video>
```

and then just fill the value during Page_Load event

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim VideoUrl As String="http://euspsql01/prevencion/video/" & Today.Month & ".mp4"
    litSource.Text = "<source src=""" & VideoUrl & """  type=""video/mp4"">"
End Sub
```

Other options are about putting runat="server" into your current source element and setting .Attributes("src")=VideoUrl, but that would emit more HTML.